# json.dumps not correctly recognizing dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary

Here's the relevant code:

```
  print(type(document))
  myjson = json.dumps( document )
```

Here's what I get:

```
<class 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./monitor.py", line 965, in <module>
    myjson = json.dumps( nft )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

So type() thinks its a dict, which it is but dumps() thinks its a Decimal.  Now what?

I tired assigning it to another variable thinking it was the name that was throwing things.  No difference.  type() thinks its a dict, dumps() thinks its a Decimal.

Comment: The dict contains other data with their own types inside of it. Some value within your dictionary has the type of `Decimal` which is not json serializable.

Comment: You do realize that "Decimal" is not a valid python type, right?

Comment: Also tried using simplejson.  All that happened was that it now complains about it being a datetime instead of a decimal.

Comment: `Decimal`, even if it is not a python base type, is a type defined by whatever library you're using. If you could update the question to show what your data consists of, then I may be able to help

Comment: Looked at https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-object-of-type-decimal-is-not-json-serializable.  That did not work.  The extra processing never gets called.  The thing to keep in mind here is that "Decimal" is not a valid python type.  Python uses "float" instead.  I even went so far as to convert any floats in the document to there respective strings.  Still get a Decimal error even though everything is strings now.